# opening folder with space in it's name

Tags: git-bash

**Hello, am using gitbash on windows and i want to use the command 'start' to open a folder named 'New folder' , but it opens the CMD !! please help ?**

Answer (score 1):

Pass `'New Folder'` twice:

```
start 'New Folder' 'New Folder'
```

If the first argument to `start` command is a quoted value, `start` interprets it as the new command window title so you need to pass the actual parameter as the second argument if it is a quoted string. (N.B.: the first argument may actually be any quoted string in this case.)

Comment: Thank you sir ! that was completely helpful